# Extract lower off diagonal elements from numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have below array

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[7412, 33, 2],
              [2, 7304, 83],
             [3, 101, 7237]])
```

I would like to extract only lower off-diagonal elements from above array and put them in a vector.

I tried with `np.extract(~a, a)`, but is extracting all elements.

Desired output will be `[2, 3, 101]` for above example.

Any insight would be helpful

Comment: What do you mean with "only lower off-diagonal elements"? Can you add the expected output for your given example?

Comment: Desired output will be `[2, 3, 101]` for above example. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.tril_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) or [`np.tri`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[7412, 33, 2],
              [2, 7304, 83],
              [3, 101, 7237]])

n, m = a.shape

# Option 1
out = a[ np.tril_indices(n=n, k=-1, m=m) ]
# Option 2 (should have equivalent output)
out = a[ np.tri(N=n, M=m, k=-1, dtype=bool) ]
```

out:

```
array([  2,   3, 101])
```